# custom public key generation for mule custom connector

Tags: mule, public-key, mule-component, connector

i have created a sample custom connector and I'm in thought of applying a 30 days trail licence for it so for that I need a public key so without getting it from mulesoft is there any possible way for creating a custom public key which helps us to create a licence if yes can someone suggest me the procedure

Thanks& Regards 
sai Kumar

Answer (score 1):

There are many tools to create key-pairs. One of those is Java's `keytool` command line tool. You can find information [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/security/toolsign/step3.html) on how to use it to generate keys. Another recommended tool (based on that one in fact) is [KeyStore Explorer](http://keystore-explorer.org/).